# forwarding to new page based on checkbox input

Tags: android

I am trying to forward to a new layout based on the selection of a checkbox entry.

What would be the process in doing so?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="127dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="PROCEED"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="108dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
    android:text="DOG"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.434"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" /> /

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="108dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="CAT"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.424"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox2" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by forwarding?

Comment: Forwarding as a a linking to new page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You implement `OnCheckedChangeListener`. More information [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener).

```
yourCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {      
        if(isChecked) {
        //launch activity, change fragment, load view, 
        }
        else{
        //whatever you want
        }
    }
});
```

Or you can set an attribute that change its value according to the checked checkbox and use that attribute in the implementation of what happens when you click the button.